# Operate on different kinds of Android widgets at once

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

In my activity, the user performs a search, and there are ~10 filters for the search. Some of the filters are `EditText` and some filters are `Spinner`. I want to display a message if the user tries to perform an empty search(i.e search without any filters). For this I have this method:

```
 public boolean emptySearch(){

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(ticketID.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else if(productID.getSelectedItemId()!=0){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_summary.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else if(severity.getSelectedItemId()!=0){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(customerID.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(version_target.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(created_by.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(date_start.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(date_end.getText().toString())){
            return false;
        }
        else 
            return true;
    }
```

(The first option in the spinners is a default dummy option).

This code looks like a mess though, and I feel it is somewhat unnecessary.

I was wondering if it's possible to write some isViewEmpty method like:

```
 public boolean viewIsEmpty(EditText et){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString()))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
 public boolean viewIsEmpty(Spinner sp){
        if(sp.getSelectedItemId()!=0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

And then store each of the views in an `arraylist<View>` and simply call `viewIsEmpty()` on each element of the `Arraylist` in a `for(View v: views)` loop. Then I could get rid of that huge cumbersome peice of code, but I am unclear how to proceed since I cannot call `viewIsEmpty(v)` on a `View` instead of a `EditText` or `Spinner`. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own generic tester. you just have to write once the test for each type of View this tester can be really generic an you can use it every time you want to do the same kind of check.

```
public class ViewTester {

    private ArrayList<View> viewToTest;

    public ViewTester(){
        viewToTest = new ArrayList<View>();
    }

    public void add(View v){
        viewToTest.add(v);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        Iterator<View> it = viewToTest.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            View v = (View) it.next();
            if(v instanceof EditText){
                String s = ((EditText)v).getText().toString();
                if(s != null && s.trim().length() > 0 )
                    return false;
            }else if(v instanceof Spinner){
                long i = ((Spinner)v).getSelectedItemId();
                if(i > 0)
                    return false;
            }else if(v instanceof DatePicker){
                // ...
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity you just have to register all view you want to test before checking their content

```
ViewTester tester = new ViewTester();
tester.add(ticketID);
tester.add(productID);
tester.add(desc_summary.getText());
//...

if(tester.isEmpty()){
    // Show message
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yeah I guess I will implement something similar.